# Laravel Mix and webpack-dev-server : Changed files not refreshing?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, laravel-mix

I'm struggling to get Laravel Mix and webpack-dev-server working together correctly. Mix works fine for bundling assets to files, and using "watch" mode also works correctly.

When I try using it with webpack-dev-server, I hit problems. The in-memory "build" seems to works, and the dev-server is serving up assets (so not a cache problem) - but it's serving stale ones from storage, rather than the in-memory versions. If I change a source file I see the rebuild in the console, but still the stale assets get served if I hit F5. (The stale assets are from a previous 'regular' Laravel mix build)

Here's my webpack.mix.js

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix').mix;

mix.ts('resources/assets/ts/app.ts', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/css/webcentre.scss', 'public/css')
   .webpackConfig({
     devServer: {
      proxy: {
        "!**/*.(js|css)": { target: "http://localhost:8000" },
      }
    }
  });
```

"yarn serv" does this:-

```
  "serv": "webpack-dev-server --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
```

Accessing `http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server` returns a valid HTML page - but there's no visible content - just an empty `<ul></ul>` list.

I have found a hack that fixes this, after looking at the source, but I can't see why it's needed. Adding the following to the .webPackConfig block makes the above URL return sensible data, and everything works as expected.

```
output: { path: '/' },
```